# How to bring tab to front using Firefox WebExtensions API

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing a `Firefox WebExtension` (A new technology of Firefox Add-on, in order to make Chrome extensions compatible with Firefox).

Now I need to bring a specific tab to front by tab id.

I tried `chrome.tabs.update(this.id, { selected: true }, callback);`. This works for Chrome, but Firefox doesn't support `selected` property (And doesn't support `highlighted` either).

Does anybody know how to do this?

[Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/update) of `chrome.tabs.update`. No other property seems the one I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the [`active` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/update#Parameters) for [`tabs.update()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/update). This also works in Chrome.

You should use:

```
chrome.tabs.update(this.id, { active: true }, callback);
```

My answer to [From a browser action popup: open a new tab and fill input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41094570/3773011) shows using `chrome.tabs.update(tab.id,{active:true})` in an extension to activate a tab which had been opened by the extension without making it the active tab at the time the tab was opened.

Comment: That's odd. I've tried `active` before, but not working. I tried again after saw your answer, this time it worked...

Comment: Hmmm... strange. Hard to determine what it might have been. At least it is fixed now.